# Where to consume messages from RabbitMQ in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm working on setting up microservices and at the moment I can get a message published from the queue which is great but how and where should I consume that message on a separate microservice app (also using Laravel/Lumen)?

Where do i register the "consumer"? my first thought is in the register method in the app service provider but that doesn't seem right. I just need to be pointed in the right direction as I have found many examples outside of a laravel app but literally nothing on where to register a consumer specifically for Laravel.

Comment: Did you try: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/1

Comment: Where did you end up adding the consumer?

Comment: You could use enqueue/laravel-queue package to consume messages from RabbitMQ https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/laravel/queues.md